# Perl - reading all the files in a directory with the extension".css"

Tags: perl, search, dir

I'm planning to convert a Perl file into an executable file so that when you run the executable, it should detect all the `*.css` files in the current directory and throws the output.

Is there a way to do this? I have a written the program below and it's throwing up an error message. Can you please help me fine tune this?

Please bear with me since I'm trying to learn Perl. The directory to be read is `bin`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @files;
opendir(bin, $Directoryname) or die "cannot open directory $Directoryname";
@files = grep(/\.css$/, readdir(bin));

# my $regex = qr/
# (?=.*font-size) &&
# (?!.*%)
# /ix;

foreach $file (@files) {

  open my $handle, '<', $file or die "could not open '$file': $!";

  while (my $line = <$handle>) {

    if ($line =~ /font-size/) {
      if ($line !~ /%/) {
        print "\n Forced Font is detected. -- $line\n";
      }
      else {
        print "\n Font is specified in % -- $line \n";
      }
    }

    if ($line =~ /line-height/) {
      print "\n Forced Line-height is detected. \n";
    }

    if ($line =~ /position:absolute/) {
      print "\n position:absolute is detected. \n";
    }
  }
}

close(txt);
```

This is giving the output:

```
cannot open directory at C:\Perl64\bin\sample1.pl line 4.
```

Comment: I have indented your Perl code for you. In future, it is fine if you want to punish yourself by writing badly-formatted code that is difficult to read, but if you are asking others for help with it then please have the courtesy to lay it out properly.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$Directoryname` has no value associated with it.

You should set it with something like

```
$Directoryname = 'bin';
```

That said, in order to find all *css* files, I'd use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @files = glob('*.css');
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `$Directoryname` is blank or undefined where do you assign a value to it?

Add `use strict;` at the beginning of your script, to see where you have other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Check docs for [`opendir/readir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) and how they should be used,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Directoryname = "bin";

opendir(my $dir, $Directoryname) or die "$! $Directoryname";
my @files = grep(/\.css$/, readdir($dir));
# ..
```

Comment: I made the below modifications :    my @files;  
 
my $Directoryname = '/bin'; 
opendir(bin, $Directoryname) or die "cannot open directory $Directoryname";  
@files = grep(/\.css$/,readdir(bin));  
 
foreach $file (@files) {  
open my $handle, '<', $file or die "could not open '$file': $!";  
 while (my $line = <$handle>) {  
 
Still facing the same error

Comment: @mohad You're missing full path to file => `open my $fh, "$Directoryname/$file";`

Comment: Where should i add this? I'm pretty unsure

Comment: You made some changes that made your code worse: so you omitted `$!` in the error message. Please add that, and add "use strict; use warnings;" too. All of this will simply tell you, what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys ! I fixed the issue...Went through the readir/opendir and learned how to code this !